# Duplicate query issue in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am working on one module in yii2 and please count me as a noob in this. I usually work in Laravel.

My query looks as below.

```
 $query = SomeModel::find()
 ->joinWith(['relation1 s', 'relation2 r','relation3','relation4 c'])            
 ->where(some where contions)
 ->where(some where contions);
```

The issue is in the view the yii2 debugger (Database Queries) shows **"187 duplicated queries found."**
My model doesn't have any loop around the query.

I have tried with removing `joinWith` relations but it will increase the duplicate queries to 220.

The query which gets repeated is one `SELECT` query

```
SELECT * FROM `relation4` WHERE `id`= 2159
```

I have checked the "relation4" model but it has nothing suspicious in it.

What should I do or where should I look to resolve this issue??

Comment: Looks like the loop would be in your join. It is joining that one piece of data many times over. I'm not sure about yii2. Where is your `ON` statement?

Comment: You should take a look to the difference between [lazy loading and eager loading](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record#lazy-eager-loading) in Yii Active record. And the second where() has to be written as ->andWhere(...)